# 'Snap during transform' not doing anything

Tags: modeling, workflow, vertices, snapping

I've encountered a strange problem with the snap during transform setting, where it seems to be being ignored.

I've tried toggling it on/off, using the different snap modes (to vertex, edge, face, etc), snap targets, but the behavior that I previously had (being able to drag a vertex towards another and have it snap) seems to have been lost somehow.

I'm assuming I accidentally hit a key combo that changed something but I'm fairly new to blender so I'm not sure what that would be.

Hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> seems to move the vertex some units in a direction, but doesn't actually snap it to the nearby vertex.

Here's a quick image of what I'm experiencing:
[image]

I should mention that snapping to grid seems to work fine - all other snapping methods do not.

Comment: I have never understood the snap system in blender, I use "double g" when i need to slide parts of my mesh.

Comment: Do you have *Snap to itself* option activated which is just to the right of snap buttons ? It's not seen on your gif.

Comment: @MrZak thx for your comment. Post expanded.

Comment: Looks like you have non-manifold geometry which bumps you...

Answer (score 6):

The reason why it does not seem to work is that the mouse cursor is not hovering exactly over the vertex which is to snap.

---

1. Enable *Snap during transform* by clicking on the red Magnet symbol or by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.
2. Choose *Vertex* as Snap Element
3. Enable *Snap onto itself*

   [image] 

   *If *Snap during transform* is disabled you can hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> during Translation (<kbd>G</kbd>).*

---

- Hover the Mouse cursor over the desired *Vertex*

  Make sure you hover exactly over the *Vertex* otherwise it won't snap

  [image]
  *A little circle will appear on the Vertex*

---

Another possibility to achieve the desired result is to **Merge** the *Vertices*

- Select the two Vertice by holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click <kbd>RMB</kbd>
- Press <kbd>W</kbd> and choose *Merge*
- Choose *'Merge at Last'* or *'Merge at First'* depending on the selection order

  [image]

Comment: Sadly this didn't seem to be the issue - Reinstalling blender and copying my project into a new fle (within the original file the issue persisted) seemed to get snapping working again, and I haven't run into it since.

Comment: @LucasPenney maybe you want to upload the ~.blend file?

Answer (score 3):

And check Proportional Editing mode is Disabled. Snapping doesnt work with it :)  [image]

Answer (score 1):

I came here with the same problem and found my solution in the comments so I will add it as an answer.

"Do you have Snap to itself option activated which is just to the right of snap buttons ? It's not seen on your gif. – Mr Zak Apr 1 at 15:05"

I did have Snap to itself deactivated. After activating it snap started working again.

Answer (score 1):

One importante thing about the snap transform. It doesn't work if you display a Subdivision Surface Modifier. Maybe here is the only reason why you encountered this issue.